# Which X-Men movies' timelines were erased by Days of Future Past?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, chronology, x-men-days-of-future-past

In *Days of Future Past* (2014), Wolverine erases the old timeline and starts a new one.

Which X-Men films' timelines were erased?

<sub>Please no spoilers.</sub>

Comment: Also see: [In what order should I watch the X-Men movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52703/27264)

Comment: Those questions generated useful answers pertinent to this one, but this question is distinct.

Comment: It doesn't seem too distinct, though. Both ask where with respect to the timeline the individual movies lie.

Comment: *"Please no spoilers"* - I'm afraid we might not be able to answer your question satisfactorily without any discussion about the individual movies' stories at all. But answers could at least try to hide specific details behind spoiler blocks, provided the answer still makes sense without them.

Answer (score 8):

[Per Writer and Producer Simon Kinberg](http://collider.com/x-men-days-of-future-past-ending-explained/), "erased" is not an accurate description of how the timelines have been affected. As such, it is only a matter of opinion to state which aspects of the various films may no longer be relevant to timelines moving forward from *DOFP*.

> “The end of Days of Future Past in 1973 does change the timeline of the established film universe.  But one of the things we posit in the film is the immutability of time.  So what you see at the end is a future that has been shifted but not completely transformed.  Our characters are back in the mansion, as we saw them in X1-3, with some obvious changes (like certain characters being alive).  So the answer is yes and no.  Yes it changes the timeline.  No it doesn’t completely erase everything…”
>
> “Characters can change, but, like time, they are on a general path that cannot be completely undone.”
>
> -- Simon Kinberg

---

Unlike, for example *Back To The Future* (1985) where time travel to the past can literally *erase* things from the future, the immutable timeline which Kinberg posits may *shift* the details of the timeline without erasing anything.

[image: Back To The Future's mutable time erases things]

[image: X-Men Wolverine travels through immutable time]

Comment: apparently, modifying an immutable timeline is painful.